# How to provide an emoji picker for Draft.js

Tags: emoji, draftjs

I'm using Draft.js with draft-js-plugins's Emojis and I wonder if there's a way to provide an emoji picker (like in WhatsApp iMessage etc.) for the user. The only way now is to type a colon and get suggestions based on a keyword. All my users find this very irritating. Any ideas?

Comment: I not know `draft-js-plugins` , it's not an official addon for 'draft-js'. If you're tring to use `draftjs` directly, I can provide helps.

Comment: I am also having the exact requirement. What I am doing is, trying to match the stickers plugin with my requirement. Doesn't it helped to you ? Anyway you can write  your own plugin.

Comment: @ErangaKapukotuwa do you have a demo that I can try out? Would be really interested! Maybe we could write a plugin for this together?

Comment: @PhilipClaren Sorry at the moment I don't have a public deployment of sticker integration. Sound is good for me about writing a emoji picker plugin.